# JLine autocomplete not showing and running onComplete after pressing enter

Tags: java, log4j, jline

For some reason, my multithreaded netty server won't work with autocomplete on Windows to be specific (in my original testing linux worked fine)
I found terminal console appender and jansi to be "solutions" which they were for a lot of problems, except this one. The odd part about this is my client running the same code function to call lineReader.readLine("> "); works perfectly fine with auto complete with almost exact same code. I have no idea what is the problem because they're both calling the same code at the same order with the same dependencies (except some server-side dependencies)

Source at: https://github.com/Fernthedev/light-chat

Server read code: https://github.com/Fernthedev/light-chat/blob/master/java/server/src/main/java/com/github/fernthedev/server/ServerCommandHandler.java

Client read code: https://github.com/Fernthedev/light-chat/blob/master/java/client/src/main/java/com/github/fernthedev/client/WaitForCommand.java

StaticHandler (used for reading and setting terminal and reader): https://github.com/Fernthedev/light-chat/blob/master/java/universalChat/src/main/java/com/github/fernthedev/universal/StaticHandler.java

Both server and client have a main class with the main(String[] args) method

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: No error, that's the problem. It just inserts a tab space and if I press enter, it doesn't show the autocomplete but readLine(); does handle the autocomplete as if I did choose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I narrowed the problem being forcing TerminalConsoleAppender to make a dumb terminal so I disabled that and then fully shading jline and jline-terminal-jansi and worked perfectly.